# Tornado: passing parameter to static_url()

Tags: tornado

I have the following html:

```
<img src="{{static_url('{{DEFAULT_IMAGE}}')}}" id="xx">
```

I'm passing `DEFAULT_IMAGE=DEFAULT_IMAGE` when i call `render()` but it's not working. I have also tried the following:

with DEFAULT_IMAGE=static_url(..) but I guess that's the same problem. What's the correct way to passing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be passed to render like:

DEFAULT_IMAGE=self.static_url(DEFAULT_IMAGE)

Comment: actually you could use `{{ static_url(DEFAULT_IMAGE) }}` in template as well